# Can every Riemannian manifold be written as a statistical manifold?

Tags: differential-geometry, information-geometry

Given a sufficiently nice PDF $f:M\times \Theta \to \mathbb{R}$ where $M\subset \mathbb{R}^D$ and $\Theta\subset \mathbb{R}^p$ if the Fisher Information matrix
$$I_{ij}(\vec{\theta})=\mathbb{E}\left[\left(\partial_{\theta_i} \log f(\vec{X}, \vec{\theta})\right) \cdot \left(\partial_{\theta_j} \log f(\vec{X}, \vec{\theta})\right)\bigg|\theta\right]$$
is positive definite (PD) then it forms a metric tensor in the variable $\theta$ and we can say that $(\Theta, I)$ is a manifold, called a statistical manifold. Thus, for nice enough PDFs, we can always find an associated a statistical manifold.

**Question:**
Given a Riemannian manifold $(\Theta,g)$ with metric tensor $g$, can we find a PDF $f:M\times \Theta\to\mathbb{R}$ (for some $M$) such that $I(\vec{\theta})=g(\vec{\theta})$? If so, is such a PDF unique? In other words: is every metric tensor the Fisher information metric for some RV $X$? Another way to ask is whether every metric tensor $g$ on $\Theta$ can be written as
$$g(\theta) = - \mathbb{E}\left[\nabla_\theta^2 \log f(\vec{X}, \vec{\theta})\bigg| \theta\right],$$
for some sufficiently nice $f$?

**Some thoughts:**
I would wager that the class of manifolds is larger than the class of statistical manifolds (those whose metric tensors are the FIM of some RV). But this is just a rough guess and I am not sure what tools to use to approach this question. If anybody has suggestions or hints I would gladly expend more effort on this and add some attempts.

Comment: I know that there is another notion named "statistical manifold": namely, it is a Riemannian manifold $(M,g)$ with two connections $\nabla$ and $\nabla^*$ that are dual to each other, in the sense that $Zg(X,Y) = g(\nabla_Z X,Y) + g(X,\nabla^*_ZY)$ for all $X$, $Y$ and $Z$. Any manifold can be endowed with such a structure: take $g$ any metric and $\nabla=\nabla^*$ its Levi-Civita connection. Maybe it is related?

Comment: @Didier Interesting! I just got a copy of *Methods of Information Geometry* by Amari and Nagaoka and there is a whole chapter entitled "Dual Connections", so I'm sure I'll learn something relevant from this comment, thanks!

Comment: IIRC, every statistical manifold in the sense of being the Riemannian manifold arising from a family of PDFs possesses a pair of dual connections and thus is a statistical manifold in this other sense (this should be in the Amari-Nagaoka book).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Statistical manifolds were introduced by Lauritzen in [this work](https://projecteuclid.org/ebooks/institute-of-mathematical-statistics-lecture-notes-monograph-series/Differential-geometry-in-statistical-inference/chapter/Chapter-4-Statistical-Manifolds/10.1214/lnms/1215467061) (even if they were already known by people working in information geometry). The idea behind is precisely the one mentioned by @Didier in their comment. Note, however, that Lauritzen uses a symmetric, 3-covariant tensor called the skewness tensor $T$ instead of the dually related connections mentioned in the comment.

Then, Hong Van Le proved [here](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00022-005-0030-0) that every compact $C^{1}$-statistical manifold $(M,g,T)$ is actually a statistical model (see also [here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/225340809_Statistical_manifolds_are_statistical_models) and [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0506163.pdf)). This means that you can represent points in $M$ as probability distributions on a given outcome space $\mathcal{X}$ in such a way that $g$ coincides with the Fisher-Rao metric tensor and $T$ with the so-called Amari-Cencov tensor coming from realizing $M$ inside $\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{X})$ (probability distributions on $\mathcal{X}$).

Unfortunately, I do not remember the details of the proof, nor I remember if meaningful comments are made concerning the non-compact case.

Comment: Extremely interesting, +1. Thank you for the references. The Hong Van Le paper looks like a good read for this weekend.

Comment: I am glad I was able to help. Depending on your level of interest in more technical aspects of classical information geometry, I would suggest also the book "Information Geomety" ba Ay, Jost Le, Schwachhöfer.